# Excel not reading the empty fomulate cell as blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I wrote a formula

`=COUNTIFS(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CF:CF,"<="&O4,Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CF:CF,">="&TODAY(), Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CM:CM,"<>Orphan",Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CG:CG,"<>",Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!BC:BC,"=B")`

Now the problem is `Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CG:CG,"<>"` is not actually ignoring the blanks as the cell `CG` has hidden formula . I guess its not considering blank.

How to make `Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!CG:CG,"<>"` to filter blank. CG column might have foumalte cell but empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!$CF:$CF<=$O4)*1,
(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!$CF:$CF>=TODAY())*1,
(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!$CM:$CM<>"Orphan")*1,
(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!$CG:$CG<>"")*1,
(Excel_Export_IT_infrastructure!$BC:$BC="B")*1)
```